# How to get access to user's google calendar from React Native (expo)?

Tags: react-native, google-calendar-api, expo

I use Expo, and I want to add access to my app to users which have a Google account. Then I need to get info about Google calendars of the user which login into my app.

I implement login function using: `Expo.Google.logInAsync(options)`  (https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google). My scope look like this:

```
scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly']
```

When someone tries to login into my app, it asks about permission to see calendars list. In response I get:

```
Object {
    "accessToken": "a",
    "idToken": "b",
    "refreshToken": "c",
    "serverAuthCode": "d",
    "type": "success",
    "user": Object {
        "email": "e",
        "familyName": "f",
        "givenName": "g",
        "id": "h",
        "name": "i",
        "photoUrl": "j",
    },
}
```

I received data about the user, but I don't have any data about its calendars.
I tried to get data about calendars (https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList) with this function:

```
getUsersCalendarList = async (accessToken) => {
    let calendarsList = await fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/calenda/v3/users/me/calendarList', {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`},
    });
    return calendarsList;
}
```

In response I got:

```
 Response {
       "_bodyBlob": Blob {
         "_data": Object {
           "blobId": "67b8b161-690f-4ff6-9cee-1dce12840ebd",
           "offset": 0,
           "size": 994,
         },
       },
       "_bodyInit": Blob {
         "_data": Object {
           "blobId": "67b8b161-690f-4ff6-9cee-1dce12840ebd",
           "offset": 0,
           "size": 994,
         },
       },
       "headers": Headers {
         "map": Object {
           "alt-svc": Array [
             "quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"44,43,39,35\"",
           ],
           "cache-control": Array [
             "public, max-age=0",
           ],
           "content-type": Array [
             "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
           ],
           "date": Array [
             "Thu, 17 Jan 2019 11:30:32 GMT",
           ],
           "expires": Array [
             "Thu, 17 Jan 2019 11:30:32 GMT",
           ],
           "server": Array [
             "GSE",
           ],
           "vary": Array [
             "X-Origin",
           ],
           "x-content-type-options": Array [
             "nosniff",
           ],
           "x-frame-options": Array [
             "SAMEORIGIN",
           ],
           "x-xss-protection": Array [
             "1; mode=block",
           ],
         },
       },
       "ok": false,
       "status": 403,
       "statusText": undefined,
       "type": "default",
       "url": "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList",
     }
```

How can I get a list of user's google calendars in Expo?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the full error message.

Comment: I added the full error message. I'm not sure if the flow of getting user's calendar information is correct. Do you know how exactly it works? Can I get information about user's calendar with `accessToken` from any google account or only from application account?

Comment: could you please mention what you did for getting access to the calendar? I think first you get the authorization code from google by a google sign-in, then exchanging the code to access_token through calling `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token`, and finally, calling the scopes (e.g. gcalendar) via your access token? If so you didn't need to communicate with any backend part? isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the solution here: [React-Native JSON fetch from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51607886/react-native-json-fetch-from-url). One needs to use `json()` function on returned object.
The `getUsersCalendarList` schulde look like this:

```
getUsersCalendarList = async (accessToken) => {
    let calendarsList = await fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/calenda/v3/users/me/calendarList', {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`},
    });
    return calendarsList.json();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also add the access token as a parameter on the request.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calenda/v3/users/me/calendarList?access_token={token}
```

I am not a react dev so not exactly sure how to fix your header. It looks ok.

Comment: How can I check if it works outside of react native? I tried to execute this URL (with real token) from a browser, but I got "Not found."

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your access token it could be expired its only good for an hour.  you can test it here but you cant supply your access token https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/calendar/v3/calendar.calendarList.list

Comment: @DalmTo My access token looks like this: `ya29.GluUBkIgKjUdNVAteJqDd3YMGj_pHztwosIK6dLnHgLYUWm_2SJy5ql_AyqaOHhE-Len_EsDt1wiORY25SdV4WjH5c0w4yl-zeT5tHcNpEaFO4tqwnY7uiTwjgya`
What can be wrong with it?

Comment: It could be expired.  It could be a refresh token for that matter it could be an authorization code. Try and generate a new one.